# Tell table column not to get wider when a cell is large?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do I make a column on a table not get wider when a cell is large? here is a demo. `white-space:nowrap;` is because I want it one line. `text-overflow:ellipsis;` for the ellipsis I want (which it doesn't do) and `overflow:hidden` just in case. It completely ignores my overflow and ellipsis. Demo shows the problem (Firefox 27 and Chrome)

http://jsfiddle.net/Bp44m/1/

```
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th class="lastname">Lastname</th>      
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>      
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td class="lastname">I am a jerk I am a jerk I am a jerk I am a jerk I am a jerk I am a jerk I am a jerk I am a jerk</td>       
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>        
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>        
        <td>67</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

CSS:

```
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
}

table { width: 800px }
.lastname { width: 300px; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow:hidden; color:red;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `table-layout: fixed;` to the `<table>` element in order to set the width of table/columns by the width of the first row of cells.

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Bp44m/2/)**

```css
table { table-layout: fixed; }
```

> **[17.5.2 Table width algorithms: the 'table-layout' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout)**
>
> The `table-layout` property controls the algorithm used to lay out the
>   table cells, rows, and columns
>
> `fixed` Use the fixed table layout algorithm

Where the spec states:

> [**17.5.2.1 Fixed table layout**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout)
>
> With this (fast) algorithm, the horizontal layout of the table does
>   not depend on the contents of the cells; it only depends on the
>   table's width, the width of the columns, and borders or cell spacing.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
}

table { width: 800px }
.lastname { word-wrap: break-word; width: 300px;  color:red;}

}
```

Use `word-warp: break-word;` inside your `.lastname` class

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5VKZ6/

Comment: It's no longer a single line if I do it like that